# How does this const reference for std::pair work?

Tags: c++, stl, constants, std-pair

Consider `std::map` class in STL:

```
template < class Key,                                     // map::key_type
           class T,                                       // map::mapped_type
           class Compare = less<Key>,                     // map::key_compare
           class Alloc = allocator<pair<const Key,T> >    // map::allocator_type
           > class map;
```

Iterators to `std::map` return objects of type

```
std::pair<const key_type, T>
```

The important thing to note here is that the first member of the pair is `const`. This means that, the following reference assignment is **invalid**.

```
std::pair<key_type, T>& reference = *map_iterator;        // Incorrect, key_type is not const

std::pair<const key_type, T>& reference = *map_iterator;  // Correct
```

However, the following expression **is valid** :

```
const std::pair<key_type, T>& reference = *map_iterator;  // Correct, const reference is okay
```

So, by some mechanism, objects of type `std::pair<const key_type, T>` can be referred by reference of type `const std::pair<key_type, T>`. This is logically desirable (since `const`ness of `std::pair` implied `const`ness of both the members `first` and `second`, which is compatible with `std::pair<const key_type, T>`).

However, I am interested in knowing what C++ implementation mechanism makes this compatibility possible. I'm sure there ways of implementing std::pair where the two reference types above would not be compatible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do

```
const std::pair<key_type, T>& reference = *map_iterator;
```

`*map_iterator` returns a `std::pair<const key_type, T>&`.  You then copy initialize a `std::pair<key_type, T>` from that, and then you bind `reference` to that temporary variable.  Because you have a reference to `const`, this will extend the lifetime of that temporary to be the lifetime of the reference and you now have an element that is a copy of the one from the map.  Basically you've done

```
std::pair<key_type, T> copy = *map_iterator;
```

---

The above conversion sequence works because you are allowed up to one user defined conversion in initialization and the compiler will try to do that to give you a valid initialization.

Comment: Thanks! Can you provide some reference for the statement "you are allowed up to one user defined conversion in initialization" ?

Comment: @johngreen Sure.  Check out: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion